# jQuery: Highlight Table Row on Checkbox Change Event

Tags: jquery

I have the following table that contains checkboxes in each row. When checkbox status is changes (checked/unchecked), the corresponding row need to be highlighted  in yellow color. How can we achieve it using jQuery?

Note: I am using **jQuery 1.4.1**? "on" is not supported.

Note: I am trying to learn jQuery. Please do NOT suggest any third party plugin. I am trying to learn it though coding by hand.

```
<html>
<table class="commonGrid" cellspacing="0" id="detailContentPlaceholder_grdGarnishmentState"
style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">
            <a >
                Country Code</a>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            <a >
                State</a>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            Independent Order Status
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            Standard Order Status
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            USA
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="detailContentPlaceholder_grdGarnishmentState_lblState_0">Alaska</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="independantOrder">
                <input id="detailContentPlaceholder_grdGarnishmentState_chkIndependentOrderStatus_0"
                    type="checkbox" name="ctl00$detailContentPlaceholder$grdGarnishmentState$ctl02$chkIndependentOrderStatus"
                    checked="checked" /></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="standardOrder">
                <input id="detailContentPlaceholder_grdGarnishmentState_chkStandardOrderStatus_0"
                    type="checkbox" name="ctl00$detailContentPlaceholder$grdGarnishmentState$ctl02$chkStandardOrderStatus"
                    checked="checked" /></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #E5E5E5;">
        <td>
            USA
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="detailContentPlaceholder_grdGarnishmentState_lblState_1">Arkansas</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="independantOrder">
                <input id="detailContentPlaceholder_grdGarnishmentState_chkIndependentOrderStatus_1"
                    type="checkbox" name="ctl00$detailContentPlaceholder$grdGarnishmentState$ctl03$chkIndependentOrderStatus" /></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="standardOrder">
                <input id="detailContentPlaceholder_grdGarnishmentState_chkStandardOrderStatus_1"
                    type="checkbox" name="ctl00$detailContentPlaceholder$grdGarnishmentState$ctl03$chkStandardOrderStatus"
                    checked="checked" /></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: you have 2 checboxes....what if both  are checked ?

Comment: Got to love those ASP.NET Id morfs :)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss ive been looking for a cssclass to put in selector or something in the id... but couldnt find nothing...:)

Comment: @RoyiNamir   If any one is changed its status, it need to be kept in highlighted status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption based on your notes etc:  Highlight a row in yellow when a checkbox changes.

```
$("table").on("change", ":checkbox", function() {
    $(this).parents("tr:first").css('background-color','yellow');
});
```

Effect: If a row checkbox changes, it highlights.  Notes: Never changes to NOT be hightlighted once it IS highlighted in yellow.

EDIT: You COULD use a highlight class from your CSS such as `.highlight{background-color:yellow;}` however, on the second row, you would need to remove the background color style embedded there as that is more "specific" AND will always override the class added with `.addClass('highlight');`

previous versions syntax of a change event handler:

```
$("table").find(':checkbox').change( function() {
    $(this).parents("tr:first").css('background-color','yellow');
});
```

Slower .live handler for dynamic element addition:

```
$("table").find(':checkbox').live('change', function() {
    $(this).parents("tr:first").css('background-color','yellow');
});
```

EDIT2: There were a LOT of event management changes from 1.4.1 to 1.4.4.

It seems the change event is not firing for the 1.4.1 correctly - only fires on second change.  SO, use the click event instead:

```
jQuery('input').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).parents("tr:first").css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```

working example here:  http://jsfiddle.net/vW9vQ/1/

BROKEN .change test here: http://jsfiddle.net/vW9vQ/

***Highly recommend update to current release of jQuery on this stuff.***

Comment: How can I make it work in jQuery 1.4.1? "on" is not supported.

Comment: @Lijo - I added a static content and dynamic content example for 1.4.1 that should work well for you. NOTE: Edited for syntax error of first post of those :(

Comment: Edited code works well with 1.4.4. But it does not work correctly in 1.4.1. src="ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.1.js";. Any work arounds?

Comment: @Lijo - see my last entry. The event handlers from 1.4.1 to 1.4.4 where changed A LOT as some were broken and that is what you are seeing here - especially in the 1.4.2 release.

Answer (score 3):

Since everyone is ignoring your use of jQuery 1.4.1, here's an example that will work:

http://jsfiddle.net/applehat/F63Aj/1/

```
 $("input:checkbox").click(function ()
 {
     if($(this).is(':checked'))
     {
         $(this).parents("tr:first").data('prevColor', $(this).parents("tr:first").css('background-color'));
         $(this).parents("tr:first").css('background-color', 'yellow');
     }
     else
     {
         $(this).parents("tr:first").css('background-color', $(this).parents("tr:first").data('prevColor'));
     }
 });
```

You'll notice the JSFiddle link is uncluding jQuery 1.3 - so it if works on 1.3, it should easily work on 1.4.1.

Comment: It works well with 1.4.4. But it does not work correctly in 1.4.1. src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.1.js". Any work arounds?

Comment: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` Just place that in your header. =P

Comment: I am not allowed to use any version other than 1.4.1 in my project

Answer (score 2):

try this :

http://jsbin.com/ozarov/3/edit

this will also save the row background-color in alternating style...

```
     $("table").on("click", ":checkbox", function ()
 {
     if($(this).is(':checked'))
     {
         $(this).parents("tr:first").data('prevColor', $(this).parents("tr:first").css('background-color'));
         $(this).parents("tr:first").css('background-color', 'yellow')
     }
     else
     {
         $(this).parents("tr:first").css('background-color', $(this).parents("tr:first").data('prevColor'))
     }
 });
```

p.s. you *can elaborate* my sample based on 2 checked checkboxes...

Comment: Thanks. Currently it is highlighting only when I make an unchecked box into checked one. It need to work either way - ie. when I make a checked box into unchecked. How do we  do it?

Comment: How can I make it work in jQuery 1.4.1? "on" is not supported. [Once it is changed, it can be set as yellow]